# How to make heights of inner divs add up to the parent divs height? What role does line-height play in that?

Tags: html, css

**Here, I wanna have header-top and pages-navigation fit perfectly inside header. 
**
Here, header is 100px with 20px top padding, header-top is 32px, so pages-navigation should be 48px to fit. But it fits at line-height 58px. Also when I alter the line-height: 58px, it breaks. Anything I'm missing?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open sans", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  background-color: #f8faee;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.header_top {
  height: 32px;
}

.learning-site-name {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 5px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.pages_navigation {
  line-height: 58px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  clear: both;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.highlighted,
.not-highlighted {
  padding: 0 5px 8px 5px;
}

.highlighted {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

.not-highlighted {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #999999;
}

.pages_navigation span:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <div class="header_top">

        <div class="learning-site-name">Learning Site Name</div>

      </div>

      <!-- creating an empty span inline block to make space in between 2 spans -->
      <div class="pages_navigation">

        <span id="learning-board" class="highlighted">Learning Board</span>

        <span></span>

        <span id="content-files" class="not-highlighted">Content Files</span>

      </div>

    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `box-sizing: border-box;` of your header. When you set this property and set the `height 100px; padding-top: 20px;`, It means the real height of `header` is 80px. In another word `box-sizing: border-box;` make the padding and border count as the height of element.

The better way is to remove the height of `header` and let its children make it's height.